# Why is the output different in 2 arrays?

Tags: c++

I have a struct C

```
struct C
{
  int i;
};
```

and the main program to input and output data for the 2 arrays is designed as follows,

```
std::vector<C*> vc;
std::vector<C> vcc;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {     
        C c;
        c.i = i;
        vcc.emplace_back(c);
        vc.emplace_back(&vcc[i]);       
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vc[i]->i << " "; // expected 1,2,3,...,9 but there are garbage numbers in the list
    }
}
```

The current output becomes

> 0,-572662307,-572662307,3,-572662307,-572662307,-572662307,-572662307,-572662307,9

Comment: `vcc` most likely reallocates during the loops. which invalidates all pointers. try a `vcc.resever(10)` before the loop. Although I would suggest storing indices in `vc` and not pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the size of the vector is equal to its capacity, then adding an element to it (e.g. with `emplace_back`) invalidates all iterators and pointers/references to elements in the vector.

So, since you never assure sufficient capacity in the vector, `vcc.emplace_back(c);` may invalidate all pointers that you stored in `vc` beforehand. Accessing an invalidated pointer later with `vc[i]->i` causes undefined behavior.

Either make sure that the capacity of the vector is sufficient before you enter the loop, e.g. with `vcc.reserve(10)`, or better: Don't store pointers to elements of a vector that you intent to add/remove elements to/from.

Comment: _Don't store pointers to elements of a vector that you intent to add/remove elements to/from._ I would add: "Use indices instead because they are not affected by possible re-allocations in the vector `vcc`."

Comment: @Scheff'sCat What do you mean ? I must use pointer and I can't use reserver.

Comment: @greencross If a `std::vector<C*>` is necessary and `vcc.reserve()` is not an option (for any reasons), the only resort is to separate that into two loops: First emplace all the instances, and then populate the 2nd vector with the pointers to the elements of the first. As described in the answer: Anything what resizes a `std::vector` may cause a reallocation and invalidate all the addresses of the elements. `std::vector` grants a consecutive storage of its elements. So, a reallocation may cause that all existing elements are moved (or copied) to the new allocated storage...